# Restore encrypted Backup in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, encryption, backup

I use this code

```
USE master;  
GO  
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '1234';  
GO  
CREATE CERTIFICATE Cer
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Hello';  
   GO
```

and then backup database with this code

```
backup database Temp to disk = 'D:\Backup\temp.bak'
 WITH  
  COMPRESSION,  
  ENCRYPTION   
   (  
   ALGORITHM = AES_256,  
   SERVER CERTIFICATE = Cer
   ),
  STATS = 10
```

now I can not restore it to another server
i create this master key on another server but it dose not work

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Creating the certificate on another server won't help; it'll be different. You need to restore the key on the other instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `master key` is used to protect the `certificate` used for the backup encryption. The `certificate` is unique - specifying same name for executing the `CREATE CERTIFICATE` statement creates different certificate.

If this was not true, everyone with access to your backup would be able to decrypt it.

So, you need to export your certificate:

```
-- Backup the certificate
BACKUP CERTIFICATE BackupEncryptCert TO FILE = 'H:\MSSQL\Backup\Keys\BackupEncryptCert.cer'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'H:\MSSQL\Backup\Keys\BackupEncryptCert.PrivateKey.pvk', 
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'doodle$7')
GO
```

and then to create it on the new instance:

```
-- Restoring a certificate from existing certificate backup
CREATE CERTIFICATE BackupEncryptCert
    FROM FILE = 'H:\MSSQL\Backup\Keys\BackupEncryptCert.cer'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'H:\MSSQL\Backup\BackupEncryptCert.PrivateKey.pvk',
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'doodle$7')
GO
```

Then you will be able to restore your encrypted backup.